Calendar events not being added to Google calendar through Google API in flutter app
I am trying to add events to a Google calendar using the Google Calendar API in my Flutter app. I want it to work on web (Chrome), Android, and iOS. I have the code but I am getting an error when I run it on my local machine. here is the error:

I have added the url and port from the browser when I run it on debug mode to the credentials tab in the Google APIs & Services screen so I don't understand why I am getting this message.
When I run it on the web server, I don't get an error message but I don't get an event added to the calendar either. I have added the production url to the Authorized Redirect URIs in the Google Cloud Console.
Why is this not working?
